# How do I iterate over the fields of a ref object in nim?

Tags: reference, iterator, nim-lang

I have a `ref object` type and would like to iterate over all of its fields and echo them out.

Here an example of what I want:

```
type Creature* = ref object
    s1*: string
    s2*: Option[string]
    n1*: int
    n2*: Option[int]
    n3*: int64
    n4*: Option[int64]
    f1*: float
    f2*: Option[float]
    b1*: bool
    b2*: Option[bool]


var x = Creature(s1: "s1", s2: some("s2"), n1: 1, n2: some(1), n3: 2, n4: some(2.int64), f1: 3.0, f2: some(3.0), b1: true, b2: some(true))

for fieldName, fieldValue in x.fieldPairs:
  echo fieldName
```

However, doing so causes this compiler error:

```
Error: type mismatch: got <Creature>
but expected one of:
iterator fieldPairs[S: tuple | object; T: tuple | object](x: S; y: T): tuple[
    key: string, a, b: RootObj]
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for x: S: tuple or object
  but expression 'x' is of type: Creature
iterator fieldPairs[T: tuple | object](x: T): tuple[key: string, val: RootObj]
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for x: T: tuple or object
  but expression 'x' is of type: Creature

expression: fieldPairs(x)
```

Going through the documentation, there appear to be no iterators for ref object types, only for object types. If that's the case, then how do you iterate over ref object types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use iterators, you need to de-reference the ref-type that you want to iterate over! This may also apply to any other proc that expects an `object` parameter, but that you want to use with a `ref object` instance.

In nim, the de-referencing operator is `[]`.

So in order to work, the instance `x` of the ref object type `Creature` needs to be de-referenced before iterating over it:

```
for fieldName, fieldValue in x[].fieldPairs:
  echo fieldName
```

This will also work with any proc you write, for example like this:

```
proc echoIter(val: object) =
  for fieldName, fieldValue in val.fieldPairs:
    echo fieldName

echoIter(x[])
```

Comment: Be careful it's not `nil`, though